# Having Trouble executing function but not for loop it is in

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a function that can take in a function and an `Int`(numberOfTimes) and then call on `doFunctionXTimes()` a certain number of times. However, it only prints out "Hello Ethan" once opposed to five times. Here is my code:

```
func doFunctionXTimes(numberOfTimes: Int,function: Any) {
    for _ in 1...numberOfTimes {
       function
    }
}
func sayHello(name: String) {
    print("Hello \(name)")
}

doFunctionXTimes(5, function: sayHello("Ethan"))

//this code prints "Hello Ethan"
```

However, if change _ to i in the for loop in `doFunctionXTimes()` and then add a `print(i)` statement either above or below where I call the `function`, it will print out all of the numbers from 1 to 5. How can I make it so the function is called on as many times as the `print(i)` statement is called on and printed. Thank you. Here is my edited code printing i.

```
func doFunctionXTimes(numberOfTimes: Int,function: Any) {
    for i in 1...numberOfTimes {
        print(i)
       function
        // or the print(i) statement can here. It does not affect the output.
    }
}
func sayHello(name: String) {
    print("Hello \(name)")
}

doFunctionXTimes(5, function: sayHello("Ethan"))

// this code prints out "Hello Ethan" and then 1 2 3 4 5
```

Any help or advice is great and I hope this helps future viewers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the following code:

```
doFunctionXTimes(5, function: sayHello("Ethan"))
```

The `sayHello("Ethan")` part is a function call. So when the line of code runs, it first calls this function - before entering `doFunctionXTimes`. Then inside your code, you have:

```
function
```

This doesn't actually call the function (it's similar to putting 0 on a line by itself). To achieve what you want, you need a closure, which will "wrap around" the function that you want to call:

```
func doFunctionXTimes(numberOfTimes: Int,function: (() -> Void)) {
    for _ in 1...numberOfTimes {
       function()
    }
}
func sayHello(name: String) {
    print("Hello \(name)")
}

doFunctionXTimes(5, function: { sayHello("Ethan") })
```

Now function is passed as `{ sayHello("Ethan") }`, and `sayHello` won't be called until the function is called.

Note that function is now defined as `() -> Void`, which means it's a func that takes no parameters and returns no value. (I put extra braces around the definition because I find it improves clarity)

Answer (score 1):

You can also set it up so that you can add to the number of times it repeats simply by repeating a var set to the function.

```
func sayHello(name: String)
{
    print("Hello \(name)")
}

func repeatDoFunctionXTimes(number: Int, forFunction function:(()-> Void))-> (() ->Int) {

    var runFor =  number
    var i = 0;

    func repeater() -> Int  {


        while i < runFor {
            print(i)
            function()
            i++
        }
         runFor += 1
        return runFor

    }

    return repeater
}

var repeatFive = repeatDoFunctionXTimes(5,  forFunction: {sayHello("Ethan")})

repeatFive()
```

If you type in repeatFive() again it will print 6 times and so forth.